# Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJ NDAEL_256

Tags: magento-2.1, mcrypt

I got an error when i execute this command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade &&
php bin/magento setup:di:compile &&
#php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy &&
chown -R www-data:www-data . &&

rm -rf var/cache &&
rm -rf var/di &&
rm -rf var/page_cache/ &&
rm -rf var/generation/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/
```

the error is

> "Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJ     NDAEL_256"

when i was checking my server, and show the `phpinfo()`, the extension for mcrypt has been enabled properly, so what is the real problem? 
[image]

Comment: i also get same issue 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in  ../vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 394

Comment: how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mcrypt
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.1 isn't made for php7.2 … It looks like you're using php7.2. so just switch back to php7.1 oder php7.0 and it should work fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993399/use-of-undefined-constant-mcrypt-rijndael-128-assumed-mcrypt-rijndael-128

Run this in console

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
```

It should return

```
mcrypt
```

If not, be sure to enable module using `phpenmod` command

Another reference, for **php5** http://php.net/manual/es/mcrypt.installation.php

> Note, for Ubuntu, simply installing php5-mcrypt did not get mcrypt to work. You need to execute the following commands as root to enable it:
>
> apt-get install php5-mcrypt
>
> mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/
>
> php5enmod mcrypt
>
> service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

I got this after upgrading to Magento 2.3.1 on PHP 7.1.28 on CentOS7 without installing mcrypt and then adding it after discovering it was still required during the upgrade process.  Simply restarting php-fpm worked for me.

```
# systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, using MAMP for my Magento project running locally in OSX I receive this error when the wrong PHP version is being used because my .bash_profile is not being properly sourced or needs to be sourced again...

Make sure the php version and file you are suggesting to use are whats being used by the system by running:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

<---- in my case the php i am wanting to use is in the MAMP directory, so /user/bin/php is incorrect.

Once i source my bash_profile i am using the correct php and the error goes away.

Your bash_profile allows you to set a specific path for the php/mysql versions you are wanting to use, you could have a separate profile for each project if required:

```
$cat ~/.bash_profile  
/// below is an example of what you would use in your bash_profile in my case                                             
----
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.22/bin:$PATH
----
```

In order to use this bash profile you must 'source' the file.

```
$source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then when you check the php version it should return the correct path

```
$which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.22/bin/php
```

Hope this helps someone.